# How do I update the values inside a dictionary by returning the values summed up?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, updates

In this problem, the parameter collapse_values takes in a dictionary and has to update the values, which have integers inside a list into a sum. E.g: {'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]} becomes {'a': 6, 'b': 15}, which I have to check if it matches the dictionary provided in the main function.

```
def main():
    data = {'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}
    collapse_values(data)
    print(data == {'a': 6, 'b': 15})

    data = {'h':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'e':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'l':[2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'o':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
    collapse_values(data)
    print(data == {'h': 5, 'e': 5, 'l': 10, 'o':5})

def collapse_values(dict1):
    for value in dict1.values():
        value_sum = sum(value)
    if value_sum not in dict1:
        dict1[value] = value
    return dict1

main()
```

I tried iterating through the values of the dictionary only and summing the values up, and try to update the values if it hasn't already.

I get this error however, "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have catch the returned value(no problem if you not cathed , data will be changed) and also make sum on dict's value which is a list:

```
def main():
    data = {'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}
    data = collapse_values(data)
    print(data == {'a': 6, 'b': 15})

    data = {'h':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'e':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'l':[2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'o':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
    data = collapse_values(data)
    print(data == {'h': 5, 'e': 5, 'l': 10, 'o':5})

def collapse_values(dict1):
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        dict1[key] = sum(value)
    return dict1

main()
```

output:

```
True
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary-comprehension summing the values using `sum()`:

```
{k: sum(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

where `d` is the dictionary.

In Function:

```
def collapse_values(dict1):
    return {k: sum(v) for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if value_sum not in dict1:
        dict1[value] = value
```

will not work since you interate through `dict1.values()`

you can change the code like this:

```
for value in dict1:
    value_sum = sum(dict1[value])
```

and update the value :

```
dict1[value] = value_sum
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below logic to calculate sum:

```
dict1= {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}

for key in dict1.keys():
   dict1[key] = sum(dict1[key])

dict1
['a':6,'b':15]
```